# Connect to tpu from jupyter notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using GCP TPU VM. I can connect to the tpu from shell, but using anaconda's jupyter notebook with the same xrt_tpu_config it doesn't connect to the tpu.
Can you help with this.